# Как отсортировать файл в c#?

Tags: c#

Имеется текстовый файл типа

> Пассажирский самолет рейса 35898 имеет грузоподъёмность  500 тонн

И в каждой следующей строке меняется только грузоподъёмность. Как отсортировать файл по возрастанию грузоподъёмности?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как он сводится к выполнению работы за автора.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он сводится к выполнению работы за автора.

Answer (score 3):

Читаем всё, сортируем по числу тонн, пишем.

```
File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", File.ReadAllLines("input.txt").OrderBy(s => int.Parse(Regex.Match(s, @"(\d+)\s*тонн").Groups[1].Value)))
```

Это если гарантируется правильный формат строк.

Answer (score 0):

Проблемно на самом деле редактировать файл "на лету". Придется наверно построчно его прочитать в какой-то контейнер, потом отсортировать последний и записать обратно в файл. Если меняется только грузоподъемность - то хранить в контейнере можно только эти значения (и сортировать только их), чтобы память лишнего не использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отсортировать строки вида "Пассажирский самолет рейса 35891 имеет грузоподъёмность 500 тонн", существует простой и надёжный способ. Можно просто воспользоваться Local DB, так как известно, что с сортировкой лучше всего справляется SQL Server.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main ()
    {
        var v = string.Join(",", File.ReadAllLines("input.txt").Select(l => "(N'" + l.Replace("'", "\'") + "')"));
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;")) {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
                command.CommandText = string.Format("select a from (values {0}) t(a) order by" +
                    "convert(int,substring(a,charindex(N'ь',a)+2,charindex(N'то',a)-charindex(N'ь',a)-3))", v);
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    while (reader.Read())
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А за что минус? Откомментируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Vlad, я минус не ставил, но, вероятно, минус за нерациональное использование базы данных. Она тут как бы не нужна. C# имеет строенные средства сортировки, которыми и следовало воспользоваться. Если же предполагалось, что данных настолько много, что держать их все в памяти одновременно нельзя, то это решение тоже не подходит, ибо `File.ReadAllLines` возвращает массив, т. е. все данные в этот момент уже находятся в памяти. И ещё, я не уверен, что тут насчёт sql injection. Способ экранирования апострофа обратным слешом вместо дублирования тоже вызывает подозрения.

Comment: А, тут же вообще помещения данных в базу нет - формируется один большой сортирующий запрос. Т. е. все данные заведомо находятся в памяти, да ещё и в нескольких экземплярах.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Мне казалось, от фразы «так как известно, что с сортировкой лучше всего справляется SQL Server» за версту несёт сарказмом.

Comment: @VladD, ну, я её воспринял как-то как: если данных много и их следует сортировать в файлах (т. е. без всех данных полностью в памяти), то C# это делать не умеет, а если использовать sql server, то можно обойтись без написания собственной сортировки :) В любом случае, минус не мой - я их вообще крайне редко ставлю.

Comment: Пожалуй да, что-то я перемудрил)